# AttributeError: Unrecognized option 'group_dict'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I am new to tornado. I am trying to group the values using 'group_dict'. Please see the below information.

```
define('foo', group='my_group')
define('bar', group='my_group')
application = Application(handlers, **options.group_dict('my_group'))
```

But It gave an error shown below,

```
    94         if isinstance(self._options.get(name), _Option):
     95             return self._options[name].value()
---> 96         raise AttributeError("Unrecognized option %r" % name)
     97 
     98     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: Unrecognized option 'group_dict'
```

Please solve my problem. Thanks..

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: <ipython-input-10-e18bf0252f9d> in <module>()
----> 1 application = Application(handlers, *options.group_dict('my_group'))

/home/nyros/Desktop/newprojects/DJANGO/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/options.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
     94         if isinstance(self._options.get(name), _Option):
     95             return self._options[name].value()
---> 96         raise AttributeError("Unrecognized option %r" % name)
     97 
     98     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: Unrecognized option 'group_dict'

Answer (score 0):

The `.group_dict()` option was only added in Tornado 3.1 (currently in development). You'll need to upgrade your Tornado library to use it, using a checkout or download from the [Tornado GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/tornado).

See the [3.1b1 release notes](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/releases/next.html#tornado-options):

> `tornado.options.options` and other `OptionParser` instances support some new dict-like methods: `items()`, iteration over keys, and (read-only) access to options with square braket syntax. `OptionParser.group_dict` returns all options with a given group name, and `OptionParser.as_dict` returns all options.

If you are new to Tornado, you may want to stay away from the bleeding edge and use a released version instead.

Comment: I am try to configure twitter app using following link https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/twitter/twitterdemo.py

Comment: Then that application requires Tornado 3.1 at least, but the current stable release is 3.0.

Comment: I included how you solve that problem in my answer; you check out the full Tornado source code, or use the Github download link to get the most recent version as a zip file. However, **if you do not know how to run that** then you may be too far out of your comfort zone.